# How to create threads in haskell?

Tags: multithreading, haskell

How to create threads and assign tasks to them? Is there any way to do it, like usage of

```
thread.start_new_thread ( function, args[, kwargs] )
```

in Python?
thanks in advance

Comment: A question identical to this one was asked [three hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40722552/2751851), and there was at least another one over the last few days.

Comment: @duplode it is, because I didn't get answer yet.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question repeatedly just because you didn't get the answer you wanted. That just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: so.. instead of helping us to answer that question you just create a new account and re-post the same question ?.. that's rhetorical, I don't actually want an answer to that.

Comment: @duplode if you would write this code for me, I won't

Comment: @DuaneLortie nobody wants! that's why i every time try to rephrase it

Comment: @DuaneLortie that's not about Python, it's about Haskell

Comment: yes, I inked to the wrong one..  Point is, plenty of info and examples if you just search for "haskell multithread"

Answer (score 5):

Haskell threads can be spawned using [`forkIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:forkIO).

I recommend also reading the [GHC concurrency guide](https://wiki.haskell.org/Concurrency), since it has all the relevant pointers.

Comment: thanks! I've already read it and even tried some examples. Problem is that I can't rewrite this parallel example using threads, not 'par' and 'pseq'. http://www.stolaf.edu/people/rab/pub/PDC/I15/Pi_Integration_SharedMemory_html/Haskell/Haskell.html
That's what I need: to create N threads and assign different parts of list to them.

Comment: @i1698011 What did you try? Where did it go wrong? I encourage you to open a fresh question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).