# Haskell Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’

Tags: haskell

This is the  code of my program:

```
funct :: Double -> Double
funct x = 3/(x^2+1)

zetaRange :: (Int, Int) -> [Double]
zetaRange (x,y) = [ 0.01 * funct n | n <- [x..y] ]
```

and error, which I'm getting:

> Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’ with actual type ‘Int’
>
> In the first argument of ‘funct’, namely ‘n’
>
> In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘funct n’

I really newbie to haskell, so trying to fix this error wasn't successful. funct is returning Double, so I can't understand why error says that it's actual type is Int. Please, help!

Comment: Why is this tagged with "multithreading"? The question has nothing to do with multithreading.

Comment: Wait. Aren't you the same user that asked two question about Haskell and concurrency? Your user name is [eerily familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726052/how-to-create-threads-in-haskell)…

Comment: It says **in the first argument** of 'funct'. Not in the return type!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the `Int` `n` to a `Double`:

```
zetaRange (x,y) = [ 0.01 * funct (fromIntegral n) | n <- [x..y] ]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But after I changes this function a little it gives another error. Please, see update

Comment: @i1892700 please don't edit your questions once the original problem is solved. If you run into new problems, you may (after you've tried and failed to solve them yourself!) ask _a new question_ about them.

Comment: @i1892700 If my suspicion is right, you might also want to consider not making a new user for every question... You can just post new questions with the same account.